# Smallest Difference Between 2 object in Dataframe

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Stock'  : ['Apple','Broadcomm','Citi','D&G'],
                  'PE' : pd.Series([1.5,3.9,5.6,6.8]),
               })
```

I'm looking for an algorithm to rank stock pair from a pool based on the difference of PE i.e PE stock 1 - PE stock 2

i.e pool of 40 stocks, rank based on unique stock pair based on smallest PE difference. Total will have 20 unique pairs
eg. MSFT appears in pair 1, with smallest PE associated with MSFT pair, MSFT should not reappear again in the subsequent pair

What's the correct algorithm for doing this?

So far I have tried to find the PE difference of each and every pair and rank ascending. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pandas base solution:

First make the matches :

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Stock'  : ['Apple','Broadcomm','Citi','D&G','Samsung','Elite'],
                  'PE' : pd.Series([1.5,3.9,5.6,6.8,6,6])})
df.set_index('Stock',inplace=True)
df.sort_values('PE',inplace=True)               
crosstable=pd.DataFrame(add.outer(df.PE,-df.PE),df.index,df.index)
v=crosstable.mask(triu(ones((len(df),len(df)),bool))) #keep valid comparisons
```

Then `v` is :

```
Stock      Apple  Broadcomm  Citi  Samsung  Elite  D&G
Stock                                                 
Apple        NaN        NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN
Broadcomm    2.4        NaN   NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN
Citi         4.1        1.7   NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN
Samsung      4.5        2.1   0.4      NaN    NaN  NaN
Elite        4.5        2.1   0.4      0.0    NaN  NaN
D&G          5.3        2.9   1.2      0.8    0.8  NaN
```

Then the classement :

```
w=v.stack()
w.sort_values(inplace=True)
```

`w` is :

```
Stock      Stock    
Elite      Samsung      0.0
Samsung    Citi         0.4
Elite      Citi         0.4
D&G        Samsung      0.8
           Elite        0.8
           Citi         1.2
Citi       Broadcomm    1.7
Samsung    Broadcomm    2.1
Elite      Broadcomm    2.1
Broadcomm  Apple        2.4
D&G        Broadcomm    2.9
Citi       Apple        4.1
Samsung    Apple        4.5
Elite      Apple        4.5
D&G        Apple        5.3
```

And extract the best pairs :

```
i=0
s=set(df.index)
top=[]
while s :
    x,y = w.index[i]
    if x in s and y in s :
        top += (x,y),
        s -= {x,y}
    i+=1
```

`w[top]` is  the result:

```
Stock      Stock  
Elite      Samsung    0.0
D&G        Citi       1.2
Broadcomm  Apple      2.4
```

Comment: Maybe the while loop can be replaced with `w.drop_duplicates(subset=[0,1], inplace=True)`? (Maybe requires reindexing?)

Comment: Don't think there is so simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach that uses `itertools.combinations()`, `isin()`, and `drop()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it

df = pd.DataFrame({'Stock' : ['Apple', 'Broadcomm', 'Citi', 'D&G', 'Elixir', 'Foxtrot'],
                   'PE'    : [3.8, 3.9, 5.6, 6.8, 0.5, 3.9]})
print(df)

assert len(df) % 2 == 0
m = df.set_index('Stock')
ranking = pd.DataFrame(columns=['StockA', 'StockB', 'minPE', 'deltaPE'],
                       data=[(a, b, min(m.PE[a], m.PE[b]), abs(m.PE[a] - m.PE[b]))
                             for a, b in it.combinations(m.index, 2)])
ranking.sort_values(['deltaPE', 'minPE'], inplace=True)
print(ranking)

# ranking is sorted from best to worst.
# Start with first line, eliminate other lines that belong to either one of
# this line's stocks (but not both), then proceed to next line and repeat.
for i in range(len(df) // 2):
    a = ranking.iloc[i].StockA
    b = ranking.iloc[i].StockB
    contenders = ranking[ranking.StockA.isin([a, b]) ^ ranking.StockB.isin([a, b])]
    ranking.drop(contenders.index, inplace=True)

print(ranking)
```

Output:

```
    PE      Stock
0  3.8      Apple
1  3.9  Broadcomm
2  5.6       Citi
3  6.8        D&G
4  0.5     Elixir
5  3.9    Foxtrot

# ---- Ranking after sorting:
       StockA     StockB  minPE  deltaPE
8   Broadcomm    Foxtrot    3.9      0.0
0       Apple  Broadcomm    3.8      0.1
4       Apple    Foxtrot    3.8      0.1
9        Citi        D&G    5.6      1.2
5   Broadcomm       Citi    3.9      1.7
11       Citi    Foxtrot    3.9      1.7
1       Apple       Citi    3.8      1.8
6   Broadcomm        D&G    3.9      2.9
13        D&G    Foxtrot    3.9      2.9
2       Apple        D&G    3.8      3.0
3       Apple     Elixir    0.5      3.3
7   Broadcomm     Elixir    0.5      3.4
14     Elixir    Foxtrot    0.5      3.4
10       Citi     Elixir    0.5      5.1
12        D&G     Elixir    0.5      6.3

# ---- Ranking after dropping rows:
      StockA   StockB  minPE  deltaPE
8  Broadcomm  Foxtrot    3.9      0.0
9       Citi      D&G    5.6      1.2
3      Apple   Elixir    0.5      3.3
```

Comment: Think your algorithm is not perfect. for exemple, If you fix Apple.PE to 3.8,  min (delta PE) is not 0.

Comment: @B.M. I don't understand. When I set Apple's PE to 3.8 (or did you mean 3.9?), the result seems correct to me. Can you explain, or post the PE values and the incorrect output?

Comment: your algorithm gives  
0  Apple  Broadcomm   3.8     0.1
1   Citi        D&G   5.6     1.2
2      E          F   0.5     3.4, when the winner must be (Broadcomm,F  0).

Comment: @B.M. Now I fixed (or rather *replaced*) my answer. I think it's sufficiently different from yours to add value, but maybe you object. If you're fine with it, I'll ask OP to choose again which answer they like best.

Comment: Good effort! Let it be,  Stack overflow is for exchanges.  If the OP choose your answer first, it was better for him at this moment. I also won a lot of points with imperfect responses ...